# How to save the video to separate folder with app name in ios swift3?

Tags: swift3

I'm facing the issue while saving the video to the directory.

I'm using following code:-

let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
                let dataPath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("MyFolder")

```
            do {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dataPath.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Error creating directory: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            let filePath="\(dataPath.absoluteString)video.mp4";
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                urlData?.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true);
                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath) as URL)
                }) { completed, error in
                    if completed {
                        print("Video is saved!")
                       // self.videoAlertMeaage(isError: false)
                    }else{
                       // self.videoAlertMeaage(isError: true)

                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: Isn't it getting saved?

Comment: it's getting saved in videos.I want it in the separate folder.